# Conditional Split fails if value is NULL in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am passing result of FULL Outer join to Conditional Split and Filtering Records on the basis of following rules . Basically both tables has same schema and Primarykey values are same.

```
a. If Primary key of Source is NULL
b. If Primary Key of Destination is NULL
c. If Source and Destination key matches.
```

It works fine for (a) and (b) but fails for (c)

```
Source.Id == Destination.Id
```

and throws exception that condition evaluated as NULL where Boolean was expected. How i can make this work?

Conditional Split gets input from Merge Join and it's a FULL OUTER JOIN as i need FULL OUTER join results here

Comment: Are the three points separate conditions in your Conditional Split, or all three points are part of the same condition?

Comment: There are three separate conditions. First one checks ISNULL(Source.Id) Second one CHecks ISNULL(Destination.Id) and Thrid Condition is Source.Id == Destination.Id

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your third condition should start with a **ISNULL** check again before you compare your values. Like the following:

```
!ISNULL(Source.Id) && !ISNULL(Destination.Id) && Source.Id == Destination.Id
```

You need to handle every column that can be *NULL* in your condition.
Since you are comparing Id's, another option would be:

```
(ISNULL(Source.Id) ? 0 : Source.Id) == (ISNULL(Destination.Id) ? 0 : Destination.Id)
```

If comparing strings, you can replace the zeroes with blank spaces.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can use the following syntax:

```
REPLACENULL(Source.Id,0) == REPLACENULL(Destination.Id,0)
```