# SSIS derived column and conditional splitting

Tags: ssis

I have a column with multiple data values which I would like to split it based on the "ID" and "datetime" into subsequent new columns namely `col00_ReqID` and `col00_Datetime` in my database.

I've tried using conditional split but encountered error.

Expression used in Conditional Split:

For ReqID,

```
SUBSTRING(col00,1,10) == "Request id"
```

For Datetime,

```
LEN(col00) > 22
```

Any advice for the conditional splitting portion? Appreciate your inputs.

```
-update as of 10th March: conditional split error have been resolved. Thank you everyone for your inputs. For anyone encountering error when splitting, kindly refer to the answers provided below.
```

Desired output:
[Click for image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjd7V.png)

Comment: I think you might need to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674384/conditional-split-fails-if-value-is-null-in-ssis
it is to handle the NULL values

Comment: Do you understand that the purpose of a Condition Split is to create multiple, separate paths in a dataflow, and NOT to create multiple columns in the same path?   From the graphic in your question, it looks like you want the latter.

Comment: You want a _derived column_ transformation (to create new columns), *not* a conditional split (which creates new dataflows). In future if you encounter an error, *post it*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these conditions:

1. !ISNULL(col00) && SUBSTRING(col00,1,10) == "Request id"
2. !ISNULL(col00) && LEN(col00) > 22
3. ISNULL(col00)

in **Conditional Split Task**, handling every column that can be NULL in your conditions.

I also did this exercise using **derivated column task:**

```
SUBSTRING(col00,1,10) == "Request id" ? 
SUBSTRING(col00,14,LEN(col00) - 14) : col00
```

the task verifies that SUBSTRING (col00,1,10) == "Request id", otherwise uses the content column; 14 is the length calculated until the first number of "Request id".

I hope this help.